# Does XHTML5 require a DOCTYPE/DTD?

Tags: xml, html, xhtml, doctype

I'm [creating a language](https://github.com/SoniEx2/MDXML) that translates to XML, and it doesn't support DOCTYPE/DTD. Can I use XHTML5 without having to specify `<!DOCTYPE html>`, or am I stuck with having to implement DOCTYPE/DTD? I'd rather not, mainly to avoid language complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WHATWG](https://html-differences.whatwg.org/#doctype) says:

> In the XML syntax, any doctype declaration may be used, or it may be omitted altogether.

[and also](https://blog.whatwg.org/xhtml5-in-a-nutshell):

> The `<!DOCTYPE html>` definition is optional, but (...)

And the [W3C](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration) says:

> [The Document Type Declaration] may optionally be used within the XHTML syntax, but (...)

so we can safely assume that the DOCTYPE declaration is optional.
Also, a quick and dirty test shows that in the latest browsers, there is no discernible difference in handling files with or without a doctype declaration. As long as the file type is `.xml` or `.xhtml`.

Answer (score 3):

XHTML5 must be served with an XML media type such as `application/xhtml+xml`.  A browser will always process such resources in standards/no-quirks mode so putting `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start has no effect, and may be safely omitted.

Comment: But the question isn't about quirks mode. It isn't about HTML even.

Comment: @MrLister But the answer does say the DOCTYPE may be safely omitted. Doesn't link sources tho.

Comment: @SoniEx2 Without a DOCTYPE declaration, a file is not XHTML5. It is an unversioned type of XHTML. So if your question is "can I safely omit the doctype declaration from an XHTML file" then the answer is yes. If your question is, on the other hand, "will it still be XHTML5 if I leave out the doctype declaration" then the answer is no.

Comment: @SoniEx2 So in other words, the doctype declaration is not what makes a file XHTML. It does define the _version_ of XHTML. What defines a file as XHTML is the xmlns attribute.

Comment: @MrLister Yet you also don't link sources.